# Mongodb $lookup how to join a field with $id to $id.toString

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework, mongodb-lookup

I have a two collections

Collection1

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("5ba27d02d579d8cd47a02408"),
    NAME: "xxxx",
    DESC: "xxxxxx"
}
```

Collection2

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("5ba2900dd579d8cd47a026b7")
    COLLECTION1_ID: "5ba27d02d579d8cd47a02408"
    ORDER: 5
}
```

I'm trying to join both the collections using the following code but it doesnt seem to work, is there something I am missing? I'm doing this on Spring boot and maven version 3.7.0

```
MongoDatabase database = mongo.getDatabase("ngdesk");
MongoCollection<Document> collection = 
database.getCollection("Collection1");

ArrayList<Bson> filters = new ArrayList<Bson>();

filters.add(Aggregates.lookup("Collection2", "_id", "COLLECTION1_ID", "TEST"));

List<Document> testList = collection.aggregate(filters).into(new ArrayList<Document>());
```

Comment: It would appear based on your sample data like you're trying to `$lookup` an object id using a string or the other way round. That won't work since data types need to match.

Comment: yea im trying to match an objectId to a string version of the same id

Comment: Are you on MongoDB v4.0 already?